# Asp.Net MVC 5 ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple message system on my project. I have name property and if my User is in role Admin, I get the name by User.Identity.Name instead of getting it from View and since I made the name property required, ModelState is not being valid when an admin tries to post something.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Message,Name,Subject,Receiver")] Talep talep){
   if (User.IsInRole("Admin")){
                talep.Name = User.Identity.Name;
            }
   if (ModelState.IsValid){
            talep.UploadDate = DateTime.Now;
            var usrId = Request.Form["UserId"];
            talep.Receiver = db.Users.Find(usrId).UserName;
            talep.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
            db.Talep.Add(talep);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(talep);
}
```

Comment: First set `talep.Name` if required, then [revalidate the model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7837186/11683).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on GSerg comment, the `DefaultModelBinder` adds the error because the property `Name` is required but is null. Setting the `Name` property after the binding process does not remove the error so its still invalid. Your options include

1. Add the `Name` property to the view so it posts back
2. Remove the specific error (i.e.
   `ModelState["Name"].Errors.Clear();`) when you set the name
3. Clear all errors and revalidate (i.e `ModelState.Clear();
   TryValidateModel(crew);`)