# ASP.Net MVC : how to revalidate the entire bound model with nested objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to change the model and revalidate it without success.

After binding, `ModelState` has all values and errors.

If I change the model, and remove the errors and run `TryValidateModel()` it doesn't revalidate the model.

If I run `ModelState.Clear();` then `ModelState` will be with no values.

If I run `TryValidateModel()` again, the `ModelState` still having no values. and the validation is not completed.

The entity is a composite class with some nested attributes. The user is able to change the nested and delete or add some of then. I would like to revalidade it because, one of the nested attrib could be not valid. However user is able to delete is. If it is deleted, them i would remove it from the model and later revalidate again. However Im not able to do it.

I just want to revalidate everything. How can I do it?

Here is my Model:

```
class NestedType{
     public int propA {get;set;}
     public int propb {get;set;}
}

class MyType {
     [Key] public int Id {get;set;}
     public virtual IEnumerable<NestedType> nesteds {get;set;}
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Create([Bind()] MyType entity)
    {
        // Model "entity" is already binded

        TryValidateModel(entity); 
        // Model state here has All Keys, Values for the entity

        entity.nesteds.Remove(...)
        // Here I Removed some nesteds objects removed by the user.

        TryValidateModel(entity); 
        // Nothing changes (it should be revalidated, however this not happens) 
        // the removed nesteds still in the ModelState

        ModelState.Clear(); 
        // ModelState with no values

        TryValidateModel(entity); //THIS DON'T WORK
        // ModelState still with 0 values. 
        // the removed entries is gone, however all entries too. 
        // If there was another error in the model, this information was lost

        if (ModelState.IsValid) //true, but it does means nothing, because validation has no values. 
        {...
```

Comment: What is your purpose of re validation?

Comment: i'ts not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833396/revalidating-a-modified-viewmodel-within-a-controller-method. The solution :Clear and TryValidate, dont work here.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it answer may you @Hadee