# How to re-validate model in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model, modelstate

I have a list in model like below:

```
{
  "DepartmentId": 0,
  "Employees": [
    {
      "EmployeeId": 101,
      "EmployeeName": "Employee One",
      "DepartmentId": "1"
    },
    {
      "EmployeeId": 102,
      "EmployeeName": "Employee Two",
      "DepartmentId": "2"
    },
    {
      "EmployeeId": 0,
      "EmployeeName": "Employee Three",
      "DepartmentId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

and because of one item in the list is not valid so ModelState.IsValid returns false.
Now I have removed that item from the list like below:

```
{
  "DepartmentId": 0,
  "Employees": [
    {
      "EmployeeId": 101,
      "EmployeeName": "Employee One",
      "DepartmentId": "1"
    },
    {
      "EmployeeId": 102,
      "EmployeeName": "Employee Two",
      "DepartmentId": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, Please anyone tell me how can I re-validate model.

Below is the actual code is am using:

```
public void Settings(Companies companies)
{
    try
    {
        // This is the code that I am using to remove item from list.
        companies.Employees.Remove(companies.Employees.Find(x => x.IsActive == false && x.EmployeeId == 0));  

        // Now here I want to re-validate the model.

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // To Do
        }
    }
    catch() {}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: Can you post the code for your model, and the code where ModelState.IsValid is showing false?

Comment: clear model state and then validate again : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: DepartmentId is located both outside and inside what is your implemented model class.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revalidating a modified ViewModel within a controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833396/revalidating-a-modified-viewmodel-within-a-controller-method)